# Boost::asio async_wait handler signature

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I am going through the boost::asio examples. I am looking at 
[Example 4](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4.html)

What is confusing is that, the WaitHandler in this example has the signature

> void print (this)

But the async_wait call expects a handler whose

> function signature of the handler must be:
>
> void handler(
>     const boost::system::error_code& error // Result of operation.
>   );

[Source: Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html)

Since the parameter type is part of a function's signature, why in the example above, async_wait accepts a handler whose parameter is not of type boost::system::error_code?

THanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you correctly observe, the async_wait method accepts a handler function which takes one parameter (const boost::system::error_code&).  But in the Timer.4 example, the call to async_wait is passed via boost bind as follows:

```
timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this));
```

The boost::bind returns a function object which refers to method *print* for class *printer* for the object referenced by *this*.  This function object is called by the async_wait method with the error parameter (since that is the signature it expects).  But the error parameter is silently ignored because it is not referenced by the bind.

The official [boost::bind documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/bind/bind.html) provides more details on boost::bind.  See also the article [How the Boost Bind Library Can Improve Your C++ Programs](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=412354) (there are probably many more articles available but I found this one very useful).

Answer (score 2):

You specify in the call to async_wait what parameters your callback function takes, using placeholders. Check the sentence just above the async_wait call on the page you linked to:

> You will note that the boost::asio::placeholders::error placeholder is
> not specified here, as the print member function does not accept an
> error object as a parameter.

Search for "placeholder" in [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp) and you'll see how to do it.